# Why does a callback in setTimeout have this == Window even in strict mode?

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I am learning JS now and can not understand why 'use strict' directive does not work for a callback for setTimeout? As I know for use strict it should be undefined but always have global object.

```js
function f() {
    'use strict'
    console.log(this === window)
}

function g() {
    console.log(this === window)
}

setTimeout(g,1000) // expect true, have true
setTimeout(f,1000) // expect false, have true
```

Comment: @connexo If you replace the block with a snippet then also replace the `.log`()` calls. Stringifying `window` is a useless task in this case.

Comment: *how* a function is called can change what `this` is

Comment: @Andreas Feel free to improve.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When `setTimout()` invokes a function in the browser, it sets the `this` to `window`. That is why it is not affected by strict mode - the `this` value is provided, instead of being left unset.

The specification for `setTimeout` can be found [in the HTML standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/timers-and-user-prompts.html#dom-settimeout-dev)

> The **timer initialization steps**, given a `WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope` *global*, a string or `Function` *handler*, a number *timeout*, a list *arguments*, a boolean *repeat*, and optionally (and only if *repeat* is true) a number *previousId*, are:
>
> 1. Let *thisArg* be *global* if that is a `WorkerGlobalScope` object; otherwise let *thisArg* be the `WindowProxy` that corresponds to *global*.
>
> [...]
>
> 9. Let *task* be a task that runs the following substeps:
>
> 1. If *id* does not exist in *global*'s map of active timers, then abort these steps.
> 2. If *handler* is a `Function`, then invoke handler given *arguments* with the callback this value set to *thisArg*. If this throws an exception, catch it, and report the exception.
>
> [...]

In essence, the result is similar to calling the function like so:

```js
function f(){
 'use strict'
 console.log(this)
}

f.call(window)
```

Answer (score 2):

You may think about **this===Window** when you call a function like *f()* in non-strict mode as a default value for **this** (passed value is *undefined*).

But there is also a way to provide this value explicitly e.g.

```js
f.call(Window)
```

In that case **this** is set explicitly and no default value for non-strict **this** is needed. Both strict and non-strict functions will show the same Window.

Frankly speaking when you pass a function as a callback you do not know *how* that callback will be called and you need to check the code of a wrapper function.

setTimeout does something like that pseudofunction:

```js
function setTimeout(callback, delay, param3, param4,...){
  // waiting a timer
  callback.call(Window, param3, param4, ...)
}
```

P.S.
If you are interested in I posted couple of years ago about that - https://dev.to/smlka/easyspec-how-does-settimeout-invoke-a-callback-function-in-a-browser-44kh

Comment: thank you, this is a very clear explanation, but I would accept the first answer. And thanks for the link, I will read